# add more functionality to drupal 7 openlayers

Tags: drupal-7, openlayers

I have openlayers setup on a drupal 7 site. I can't see how to delete or move the map icons around. Do I have to edit the openlayers JS code? If so how?

Another issue I have is that I want to make one layer of content (nodes) a base layer and then have other nodes of other content types be the layers over that base layer. I've gotten so far as to have a multi-layered map with icons/layers based on taxonomy terms, but I don't know how to set the base layer (that will always stay visible).

The nodes that I want for the base layer do not have a taxonomy associated wit them. I suppose I could just give them a term in the same taxonomy category so they'd show up, but I'd still need to make it so they are always on the map acting as a base layer. (hope you can follow that)

Any help greatly appreciated.
James

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can get quite complex so I am answering a part of it. To move icons, you may need to change [CSS file](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/controls.html) instead JS. We have developed a [Web GIS portal](http://acedemo.itsc.uah.edu/map?projection=3857)  where layers are stored as Drupal nodes. And these nodes have taxonomy terms associated with them. Using those taxonomy terms, the layers are categorized into different folders. Our front end is developed using ExtJS and nodes/layers are fetched using background AJAX service calls.

Also you do not need to store base map as a Drupal node. If you are not going to support different customizable base maps, you can directly hard code base map in the JavaScript while creating OpenLayer object. See an example [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/google-v3.js) . And demo [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/google-v3.html).

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to do is to have a map of nodes showing. In this case I'll call them "sites" and that's what I was referring to as the base layer, not a map. these will be dots or polygons on the map. Then I can show the other icons on top of those by selecting links to show different things on those "sites." Make sense?

Comment: Ok, I understood some part of what you are trying to do. If you want to display dots or polygons on a map, you can create a KML file with those dots in it and ask OpenLayers to show that KML file as a Layer (and never remove it so it always stay visible). If you want to show additional things on a map, create another KML layer and add that too to on the map. So, now you will have two KML layers showing simultaneously on a map. You can display as many layers you want and hide/show any layer based on certain condition using OpenLayers JavaScript API.

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7. I created nodes and made them appear as part of an openlayers data views display.What I'm trying to do is to create nodes that are "sites" and nodes that are "things" that will be at those sites. so I'd like the icons for the sites to stay on the map and then be able to toggle the different things at those sites.I think the things and the sites will both have to be their own separate openlayers data displays.  BTW: I've seen how people have added JS to openlayers to get added functionality, but I don't know where to put this JS into openlayers on a Drupal site.suggestions?

Comment: @james Yes you are right, sites and things will be separate layers so that you can toggle one of them. And what do you mean by adding JS to OpenLayers? Are you asking about how to use OpenLayers API (using JavaScript) and then add your custom code to change default behavior of OpenLayers? Are you using http://drupal.org/project/openlayers module and trying to add your functionality into it?

Comment: yes. I didn't see how to make one of the layers stay visible, and plot the other icons on top of it. If that functionality is there, I don't see it. So I've been looking at how to edit the OL JS and haven't seen how to do it.I've seen code but not where to put it. I've seen a widget that slides in from the upper right, that lets you select layers, and I've seen a setting for layer switcher in the layers and styles page for the OL maps, but I"m having trouble getting both layers in my map page to show up and I've never seen that widget. Are you saying I can do all this from within Drupal?

Comment: I haven't used OpenLayers module, but rather created my own custom module to display OpenLayers in Drupal. Since it was a custom module, it was far easy to add my own JS code to add layers on top of a map. Once you add layers using JS, it will show them in a layer switcher.